# How do I replace the `x` in a list with another number?

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list:

```
(1 34 -5 -6 -5 9)
```

How do I replace the `-5` with `0`, for a long list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to replace all the -5's in the list you could use something like:

```
    list:(1 34 -5 -6 -5 9)     
    list[where list=-5]:0
```

This would then give

```
    1 34 0 -6 0 9
```

Answer (score 0):

List a and replace with b
`a:1 2 3 -5 6 7;`
`b:-5;`

Using the amend at(@) function
`@[a;a?b;:;0]`